# How to replace values in «groupby» (python) object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

Generally I need help in replacing one column in «groupby» object.

I have a table with customer_id, mcc_code, tr_type (transaction type) and amount (of money):

```
customer_id    mcc_code   tr_type    amount
39026145       6011       7010       56147.89
39026145       5499       1010       -1392.47
39026145       5499       1010       -920.83
78029866       5411       1010       -8709.44
78029866       5541       1110       -21897.68
78029866       6011       2010       -8983.66
```

Table is longer. I have a lot of customers, each make thousands of transaction trough different terminals (mcc_code).

Basic solution is to use «groupby» attribute and then make sparce matrix for further Classifier usage:

```
X = transactions.groupby('customer_id').apply(lambda x:  
                              x[['mcc_code']].unstack().value_counts()).unstack().fillna(0)
```

But I want to change this values from «groupby» by weighted arithmetic mean (`value[i] from value_counts * amount[i] / sum(amount)`)

I tried to do next:

```
code_counts = list(transactions.groupby(['customer_id'])['mcc_code'].value_counts(sort=False))
id_code_sums = list(transactions.groupby(['customer_id', 'mcc_code'])['amount'].sum())
sum_all = sum(id_code_sums)
weighted_mean = []
for i in range(len(id_code_sums)):
    weighted_mean.append(code_counts[i]*id_code_sums[i]/sum_all)
```

Now I have needed list of values, but they are some problems. First, before making matrix I have that (using my data):

```
X = transactions.groupby('customer_id').apply(lambda x:  
                              x[['mcc_code']].unstack().value_counts()).unstack()
print(X)
>>> customer_id
    39026145     5499    446
                 4814    138
                 6011    137
                 5331     82
                 5541     77
                 6012     13
                 5411     13
                 5200     10
                 5722      1
    52220754     6011    190
                 5411    149
                 6010     86
                 4829     76
```

First column is `customer_id`.
Second column is `mcc_code`.
Third column is how often this customer uses that mcc terminal.
I need change third column with `weighted_mean` list.
But, first, I can't understand, how to do that.
Second, order of elements in my `weighted_mean` list differs from order in third column of grouped table.
And I don't know, how to compare needed weighted means with right values from third column.

As a result, I want the same sparce matrix, but with new values from `weighted_mean` list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can  you show your desired output?

Comment: @IanS,  I want to have the same matrix, as first expression do: dropbox.com/s/99m6rxmu8on4k5a/baseline_b.png?dl=0 

You can see numbers between zeroes. It is amount, how many times this customer uses that mcc_code. So I need my new weighted means instead old counts.